# int unexpectedly turning into string

Tags: python, string, integer, variable-types

With the following snippet from a script:

```
    Tile = SelectTile()
    int(Tile)
    TileY = Tile
    TileX = 0
    #Temporary debug:
    print("type of tile is: ", type(Tile), "type of TileY is: ", type(TileY))
```

I expected the outcome to be:

```
type of tile is:  <class 'int'> type of TileY is:  <class 'int'>
```

but instead I get:

```
type of tile is:  <class 'str'> type of TileY is:  <class 'str'>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how  I can fix it? In case you need it here is `SelectTile`:

```
def SelectTile():
    print("Select Tile to put \"O\" in:")
    print("")
    print(" 1 ॥ 2 ॥ 3 ")
    print("===॥===॥===")
    print(" 4 ॥ 5 ॥ 6 ")
    print("===॥===॥===")
    print(" 7 ॥ 8 ॥ 9 ")
    Tile = input()
    int(Tile)
    #if Tile != 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9:
    #    print("Invalid Tile! Try again")
    #    SelectTile()
    return Tile
```

Comment: *return int(Tile)* is what you need.

Comment: `Tile` is a `str`, both before and after the call to `int`. No `int` value is turning into a `str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the new int value to the original variable. Here's a fix:

```
Tile = SelectTile()
Tile = int(Tile)
TileY = Tile
TileX = 0
#Temporary debug:
print("type of tile is: ", type(Tile), "type of TileY is: ", type(TileY))
```